# Authorize.net: getTransactionDetails in PHP

Tags: php, transactions, authorize.net

I'm using SIM. I perform a transaction, but Authorize.net doesn't return all the transaction details that I need in the response. So I have to manually make a call for the details after the transaction.

[This is the API I found](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/News-and-Announcements/New-API-Call-getTransactionDetails/td-p/5962)

I'm unfamiliar with SOAP. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably:

```
$soap = new SoapClient('https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL');
var_dump($soap->GetTransactionDetails(
    (object)array(
       'merchantAuthentication' => (object)array(
           'name'           => $name,
           'transactionKey' => $key),
       'transId' => $your_transaction_id)));
```

Examing the output of `$soap->__getTypes()` && `$soap->__getFunctions()` usually tells you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no reason for you to be using [SIM](http://developer.authorize.net/api/sim/). Use [direct post](http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/) it is much easier.

In fact, this is how the supplied [Authorize.net PHP SDK](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Up-and-Running-Quickly-with-the-PHP-SDK/ba-p/6722) works. So use their sdk and call the function directly.

Compared to some gateways, authorize.net has great documentaion. So learn [to read the docs](http://developer.authorize.net/api/), it will save lots of headache.

Comment: I've been through all the headaches already. This is the last one. I just need to get the transaction details. Had DPM been out when I began development, I wouldn't argue. But I've gone through the trouble of working with SIM. I just need to get the transaction details.